# Rewrite URL's with hyphens like forums do it

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite the url to my projects so the page `project.php?id=5&name=blahblah` would be `project/5-blahblah` as often seen in forums.

I only managed to do `project/5` but as soon as I add the hyphen I obviously get 404

**Edit**
Right now I got this:

```
RewriteRule    ^project/([0-9-])/?$    project.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

I also tried stuff like this but I'm terrible at regex >.>

```
RewriteRule    ^project/([0-9-][^-])/?$    project.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^project/([0-9-])([^-]*)/?$    project.php?id=$1&name=$2    [NC,L]
```

Btw. it's not so important for me to get the name since I can rely on the id but it would be nice because I might want to do stuff with it

Comment: Show us your current rules you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is incorrect.

It should be

```
RewriteRule    ^project/([0-9])-[^/]+/?$    project.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^project/([0-9])-([^/]+)/?$    project.php?id=$1&name=$2    [NC,L]
```

You used `([0-9-])` which means match any single character that is between 0 - 9 including 0 or 9 or a `-` character.

What you needed instead is match a single character between 0-9 and then match the `-` character.

And this regular expression will only work if your ID is a single digit number. For multiple number IDs, you can use `[0-9]+` instead.

Comment: Made changes in the rule to ensure it takes names with hyphen. Changed `[^-]` to `[^/]` so that it accepts any character except `/` in the name.

Comment: Try `.+` instead of `[^/]`

Comment: `RewriteRule    ^project/([0-9])-(.+)/?$    project.php?id=$1&name=$2    [NC,L]` didn't work

Comment: Both of them seemed to work when I tried them at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/. Can you please tell me what URLs you're trying?